# S3 file uploaded is getting corrupted

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some code that uploads filestream to s3 bucket. One of my customer is having some issues but I'm having trouble reproducing it on my end. Upon upload, their filesize remains at 0 bytes. This does not occur every time. Seems very sporadic.

[image]

```
using (var webclient = new WebClient())
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(webclient.DownloadData(uri)))
    {
        using (var client = new AmazonS3Client())
        {
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = GetObjectKey(fileName, companyAccountId),
                InputStream = stream
            };

            if (height > 0)
                request.Metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-height", height.ToString());

            if (width > 0)
                request.Metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-width", width.ToString());

            var response = await client.PutObjectAsync(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated to help determine why a file being  uploaded is remaining at 0 bytes.

Comment: Does the client await the async result? Does the client log the result, especially the resulting ContentLength? See if that helps to explain things.

Comment: Can you show the surrounding code? Are you doing all of the above within a using statement for `inputStream`? If not, your stream is getting closed somewhere randomly.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I've edited my code. When uploading to s3, it's enclosed in two using statements. First one is for memory stream, second is for s3 client.

Comment: @Master Can you show what `client.DownloadData` does? It may not be returning a stream correctly. Are you sure the data is always downloaded correctly / there is always something to download?

Comment: And what size is the input stream? +5GB or less?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary updated, it's a webclient and the files that are being `corrupted` are not too big. One of them that I verified is 5mb

Comment: Why do you not just set the `ContentBody` property of `PutObjectRequest` to a string created from the byte[] output of `webclient.DownloadData`? You're not streaming anything in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything else that could be consuming the inputStream and leaving the position at the end?  I have had a similar problem before and solved the problem by ensuring the stream is at the start by either

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

or

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: All our streams are within a using statement.  `using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(uri))) `
Would I have to specify position of 0 before hand? I would of thought the stream gets disposed and position gets reset within a using statement? @chrisDenning